# How host keys works in Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

As we know -Host is a key shared by all the functions hosted on a given function app.

Can we create multiple host keys in Azure Function App? If yes, Then how we can choose particular host key?

Comment: Yes you can create more than one host key. Youy api consumer  can use any any key to access the function app.

Comment: What are the steps to choose particular host key from multiple

Comment: Go to Getting your function and host keys in the Azure portal. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/portal#getting-your-function-and-host-keys-in-the-azure-portal